# Gmap in modal window

Tags: javascript, location

I am trying to make gmap geofield which is a field of a node add/edit form to work inside a popup window. I tried [ng lightbox](https://www.drupal.org/project/ng_lightbox), [colorbox](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox), [lightbox](https://www.drupal.org/project/lightbox2) and I always get the message

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined geofield_gmap.js?nuubr4:66
```

Any ideas how can I solve this?

Comment: this is issue with loading gmap api in ajax.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229695/google-maps-api-throws-uncaught-referenceerror-google-is-not-defined-only-whe